# Update two records from different tables with nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

My form is updating the tester record (which is an end user). I am also trying to update many applied_program records which belong to the tester.

I am sending the parameters to the controller but cannot get it to update the the applied_program records. It is trying to use all the parameters instead of just the applied program params to update it.

Form:

```
<%= form_for @tester, url: { controller: :admins, action: :update_tester }  do |f| %>
        <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, class: "input-lg" %>
        ...

        <%= f.fields_for :applied_programs do |fml| %>
            <%= fml.label :approved, "Approved:    " %><%= fml.check_box :approved %>
            <%= fml.hidden_field :id %>
        <% end %>

        <%= f.submit "Save Changes", class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
```

Tester Model:

```
has_many :applied_programs, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :applied_programs
```

AppliedProgram Model:

```
belongs_to :tester
```

Controller:

```
def update_tester
  @applied_programs = AppliedProgram.where(tester_id: @tester.id)
  @tester.update_attributes(tester_params)
  @applied_programs.each do |p|
    p.update_attributes(tester_params)
  end
end

def tester_params
    params.require(:tester).permit(:name, :email, :phone_number, :address1, 
                                                                 :city, :zip_code, :country, :password, :password_confirmation,
                                                                 :active, :approved, applied_programs_attributes: [ :approved, :id ])
end
```

The log:

```
Processing by AdminsController#update_tester as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"x", "tester"=>{"name"=>"Dave", "email"=>"nope@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "applied_programs_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"approved"=>"0", "id"=>"9"}, "1"=>{"approved"=>"1", "id"=>"745"}}}, "commit"=>"Save Changes", "id"=>"16"}
Tester Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `testers`.* FROM `testers`  WHERE `testers`.`id` = 16 LIMIT 1
Tester Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  `testers`.* FROM `testers`  WHERE `testers`.`remember_token` = 'x' LIMIT 1
(6.8ms)  BEGIN
AppliedProgram Load (2.6ms)  SELECT `applied_programs`.* FROM `applied_programs`  WHERE `applied_programs`.`tester_id` = 16 AND `applied_programs`.`id` IN (9, 745)
Tester Exists (0.8ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `testers`  WHERE (`testers`.`email` = 'nope@gmail.com' AND `testers`.`id` != 16) LIMIT 1
(0.1ms)  COMMIT
AppliedProgram Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `applied_programs`.* FROM `applied_programs`  WHERE `applied_programs`.`tester_id` = 16
(0.1ms)  BEGIN
(12.4ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 95ms

ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: name)
```

Comment: I assume you have a `name` attribute on your `Tester` model and not just an `attr_accessible`?

Comment: The attributes are all there in the tables. The problem is not with any tester attributes. They update fine. It when it is updating the applied program, there is only the approved attribute to update to true or false

Comment: I get that but your Log shows `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: name)`. You also shouldn't need to loop over the `applied_programs` when you added `accepts_nested_attributes` it allows you to update the associated model through the parent model./

Comment: That is during the AppliedProgram LOAD query since it is trying to update that table. The Tester table is COMMITed.

Comment: Try adding `:id` to your `tester_params` like this `params.require(:tester).permit(:id,:name, :email, :phone_number, :address1,:city, :zip_code, :country,:password,:password_confirmation,:active, :approved, applied_programs_attributes: [ :approved, :id ])`.For `update` action you need to permit `:id`.May be this causing the error.

Comment: If you keep the loop you need to not pass in the `tester_attributes` but instead `tester_attributes[:applied_programs_attributes]`. `tester_attributes` contains `name` which is why you get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is the loop over the `applied_programs` you need to do something like:

```
def update_tester
  @applied_programs = AppliedProgram.where(tester_id: @tester.id)
  @tester.update_attributes(tester_params)
end

def tester_params
    params.require(:tester).permit(:name, :email, :phone_number, :address1, 
                                                                 :city, :zip_code, :country, :password, :password_confirmation,
                                                                 :active, :approved, applied_programs_attributes: [ :approved, :id ])
end
```

Comment: Where is it updating the AppliedPrograms ?

Comment: `tester_params` has the `applied_programs_attributes`. When you update the `@tester` it updates the `AppliedProgram` since you have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :applied_programs`.

Comment: Oh I see! Awesome, +1 for the in depth help of my stubborness. ;)

Comment: Haha no problem, it is part of the Rails learning curve. Good luck